# How to update an item from ArrayList on ArrayAdapter in Android

Tags: android, arraylist, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am new at developing Android.I have a ListView and custom ArrayAdapter which holds an arraylist.I want to update arraylist specific item by position.How can I handle please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your adapter is storing a `List` of `Foo` objects.

```
Foo item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
item.setValue("blah");  //Or whatever you need to update
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```