# Unable to display data on listview

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having an issue with displaying the data on my list view that been extracted from Firebase Database. There are my codes: 
[image: code]

I hope if any of you could help me debug this error!
Thanks lads.

Comment: Please share us your database structure.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't post code as screenshot post it as in text format.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27344840/how-to-update-an-item-from-arraylist-on-arrayadapter-in-android), to update an ArrayAdapter, you need to call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method after changing the contents of the ArrayList.